# Why I can't change any configuration in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

I have all access to the admin panel by my user, I tried to use **production** and **developer** mode, I keep seeing the options locked as the image below.

**I can't click into the Use Default option, it's locked too.**

[image: Magento2 admin panel options locked]

How could I debug or solve it?

Comment: Try uncheck 'Use Default'

Comment: Ahh It seems your checkbox also disabled..

Comment: Can you please check whether your configurations are dumped (exported) in app/etc/config.php?

Comment: check console jQuery error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `app/etc/config.php`

Most likely that system configuration was locked.

system configuration can be locked by executing the following command

```
 bin/magento config:set  <path> <value> --lock-config
```

This will disable the field and **"use default"** option.

Just remove the entry you found on the `app/etc/config.php` and run

```
app:config:import or setup:upgrade
```

The command to synchronize configuration

Comment: getting this error after run :
app:config:import / setup:upgrade


Processing configurations data from configuration file...
Import failed: Area code is not set

Comment: @MageDev
Can you check if you have third-party modules that is throwing that error?