# How to enable Use in Layered Navigation field in admin panel?

Tags: attributes

I don't know why with some attributes, Use in Layered Navigation field is disabled.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the attribute you're trying to enable for Use in Layered Navigation doesn't have the proper type.
Please check the `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` option for this attribute and see if it has the proper value of `Yes/No`, `Dropdown`, `Multiple Select`, or `Price`.

Comment: It is Yes/No type, so it's weird for Use in Layered Navigation disabled

Comment: One thing I can think of is maybe you have a locked config with this attribute. Check your app/etc/env.php and app/etc/config.php files and look for this attribute.
IF you find an entry for this attribute, you will need to delete this entry and run `setup:upgrade`, for more info check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292103/why-i-cant-change-any-configuration-in-admin-panel